# What leisure activities found in Mahābhārata, Rāmāyaṇa & Purāṇa-s?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, ramayana, history

The modern world has got sports, degenerated cinema, etc. for leisure activities. I wonder what all our ancestors did as pastime?

Comment: You had the dyuta game, the theatre (The Yadavas performing Valmiki Ramayana play), dance performances, there used to be more of bonding with family, neighbours and friends and everyone was always ready for each other so talking to them was a good pastime. And the major thing was devotion.

Comment: @Archit I am kinda aware of those leisure activities. Created the thread to enumerate all with their reference(s).